# I got different answer every time when I try recognize image with neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

update 06/06/19

Hello I use this  [tutorial](https://medium.com/nybles/create-your-first-image-recognition-classifier-using-cnn-keras-and-tensorflow-backend-6eaab98d14dd).I did everything according to the instructions. But my network works as a random value generator =) Totaly missunderstand what I do wrong.I  will be grateful for any help.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
classifier = Sequential()
# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
#сжатие
classifier.add(Flatten())

#full connection
classifier.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

#compiling CNN

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary'
        )
test_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary'
        )
classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000
        )

model = load_model('my_model1.h5')

model.summary()

test_image = image.load_img('random10.jpg',target_size=(64,64,3))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
result=classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices

if result[0][0]>=0.5:
    prediction='dog'
else:
    prediction='cat';
print((result[0][0])*100)
print(prediction)
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
classifier.save('my_model1.h5')
```

I tried to increase the number of epochs but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really cannot comprehend the word "different ways" but I suppose it's mean "You got different answer every time you run this code".

The question is what are you expect from the, "not so different"?

What you are doing using this code is train it again every time you run.

You need to understand some thing first, that every time you call `classifier = Sequential()` without `classifier.load_weights()` it will initiate the weights with random numbers.

So every time you run this code, or even every code in the world with different weights, it will NEVER predict the exact same value(the `result`).

Now if what you want is for it to predict the right answer after several epochs and the current model cannot do that, what you need to do is increase the model size.

Something like this.

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

#full connection
classifier.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```